# Mustache and Express in Node

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I'm trying desperately to tie in the [mu2 module](https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu) into Express in node.js. However, I can't seem to figure it out, and when trying to run the example using the [mu2express module](https://github.com/TiddoLangerak/mu2Express), I keep getting this error when trying to run:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mu2Express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Is this an error caused by something locally, or with the module itself? Right now, I'm using the node http module to work with mu2 exclusively, but I really want to use express is possible.

Can anyone out there help? Is there more information I should provide? I'm very new to node.js and I could use some direction if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requiring the `mu2Express` module from the `myapp.js` file, so you need to install it first.

You'll need to create a `package.json` file with at least the following content:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "mu2express": "~0.0.1"
  }
}
```

And I'm not sure, that the examples are good for this project, you may need to require `mu2express` instead of `mu2Express`.

Comment: Fixed the issue! I think I was also required mu2 here as well, which since it is also a dependency of mu2express, confused it all up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Look into consolidate:

https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/

It is made by the man behind Express himself and has support for Hogan and Handlebars.

**EDIT**:

You can initialize Express with this for consolidate

```
var express = require('express');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var app = express();

app.engine('html', cons.hogan);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Renders will now be served from /views with HTML extension and Mustache-flavor syntax.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {msg: 'Hello world!'}
});
```

And a basic template, again just mustache-flavor syntax

```
Hello {{msg}}
```

Comment: This is much much better! Thank you for taking the time to show me this, and I will be using this instead of mu2express. I picked @KARASZI Istvan's answer because it answers the question directly that other stack overflowers may be looking for, but I would upvote this a thousand times if I could!

Comment: Are you familiar with how to tie this up with mustache? I replaced .swig with .mustache in the example, but I keep getting this error now:  module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mustache'

Comment: Use the express example with cons.hogan and install hogan with npm.

Comment: When you add hogan or mu2, do you have to include it in your projects dependiences in package.json? Can I store my templates in a seperate folder in hogan?

Comment: You do not have to, but it does allow `npm install` and `npm update`. Just ensure the module is installed. Express will provide the correct path to consolidate, which in turn passes it to hogan. Just configure express if you use a different folder than `views`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide any examples in your answer? I have a lot written already using the 'mu2' module, so I'm hesitant to switch to hogan. Does consolidate play well with mu2?

Comment: Hogan is a compiler for Mustache-flavor syntax. There are a lot of engines that support Mustache-flavor syntax, Handlebars and Hogan being the most well known of the two. I've added a very primitive setup for Express and hogan using HTML extension from view folder.